# Synchronization between threads without overload

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, raspberry-pi, mutex

I can't find a good solution on how to implement a good mutual exclusion on a common resource between different threads.

I've got many methods (from a class) that do a lot of access to a database, this is one of them

```
string id = QUERYPHYSICAL + toString(ID);

wait();

mysql_query(connection, id.c_str());
MYSQL_RES *result = mysql_use_result(connection);

while (MYSQL_ROW row = mysql_fetch_row(result)){
    Physical[ID - 1].ID = atoi(row[0]);
    Physical[ID - 1].NAME = row[1];
    Physical[ID - 1].PEOPLE = atoi(row[2]);
    Physical[ID - 1].PIRSTATUS = atoi(row[3]);
    Physical[ID - 1].LIGHTSTATUS = atoi(row[4]);
}

mysql_free_result(result);

signal();
```

The methods wait and signal do these things:

```
void Database::wait(void) {
    while(!this->semaphore);

    this->semaphore = false;
}

void Database::signal(void) {
    this->semaphore = true;
}
```

But in this case my CPU goes to more than 190% of usage (reading from /proc/loadavg). What should I do to reduce CPU overload and let the system be more efficient? I'm on a 800MHz RaspberryPi

Comment: Don't "implement" your own semaphore. Use an OS service instead. You *cannot* implement "sleeping" yourself, since your program can never just *not do* anything. You need to interact with the OS scheduler in order to sleep efficiently.

Comment: What do you suggest to do?

Comment: you can use `pthread_mutex_t` init at the constructor, lock for wait, unlock for signal, destroy at the destructor. or look here: http://www.sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/manual/pthread_mutex_init.html

Comment: Exactly what I said. Use an OS service.

Comment: I think you want to use `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(my_mutex);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pthread_mutex_t` init at the constructor, lock for wait, unlock for signal, destroy at the destructor.

like this:

```
class Mutex{
  pthread_mutex_t m; 
public:
  Mutex(){
    pthread_mutex_init(&m,NULL); 
  }
  ~Mutex(){
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&m);  
  }
  void wait() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
  }
  void signal() {
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
  }
} ;
```

You also should check the return value of the `pthread_mutex` functions: 0 for success, non zero means error.

Comment: with C++11, you may use `std::mutex`, and it seems that OP may use RAII, so use in addition `std::lock_guard`